# chrome.exe and "Let me use a different input method for each app window"

Tags: windows, google-chrome, keyboard-layout

When I enable the "Let me use a different input method for each app window" setting, it takes effect for different windows of e.g. notepad.exe, but not for chrome.exe.

[image: Let me use a different input method for each app window]

So if I have 2 or more notepad.exe windows, I can have different layouts on each of them. But if I have 2 or more chrome.exe windows (not tabs), changing the layout for one of them changes it for all of them.

Is Chrome doing something weird with its WNDCLASS messes up the way the setting works?

Comment: The option is actually mislabeled. It should read “Let me use a different input method for each app instance”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the language per app, not window, and Windows will remember the
setting for the next time that you open the app.

Here is how it is designed to work :

Open an app that you want to set a different language for,
and switch to the language to use.
Now close the app and open another one, and again switch to another
language to use.
The next time you open these two apps, Windows will automatically
switch to the languages as selected the last time.

For example, open Word and switch to French, next open Chrome and
switch to English, then close both.
The next time you open Word, the language will automatically change
to French. Opening Chrome, the language will be English.

The idea is to enable *your apps* to remember their preferred
input languages.

Comment: I was thinking about the 2 notepad.exe windows - I think it is per process, so even if the application is the same exe, so long as each window is a separate process. That's why notepad.exe allows you to have a different keyboard layout for each notepad window - each window is a separate instance.